# ANGULAR: How to stop the spinner from loading when authentication failed?

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I need help with my code. I'm new in angular and I have a question with regards with ngrx in effects. So inside my auth service I declared a login failed which is type observable and I want that when my authentication failed in login the spinner stops spinning and inputs the data again. What part in ngrx/effect should I add?

**SERVICE COMPONENT**

```
 public loginFailed: Observable<boolean>;
```

**NGRX/EFFECTS**

```
 @Effect()
 public login$: Observable<any> = 
  this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.LoginAction),
  mergeMap((action: Login) => 
  this.authService.login(action.payload).
  pipe(
  map((user: User) => {

    if(user.username != null && user.password != null) {
      this.authService.loginFailed
    }

    return {
      type: AuthActionTypes.LoginSuccessAction,
      payload: user
    }
  }),
  catchError(() => {
    return of({

    });
  })
))
```

**HTML**

```
 <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="button">
    <button class="btn-login" type="button" color="primary" [disabled]="isLoginBtnDisabled" (click)="onSubmit()"
        mat-button>
   <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoginBtnDisabled; else loginText">
    <mat-spinner diameter="20"></mat-spinner>
  </mat-icon>
  <ng-template #loginText>Login</ng-template>
</button>
```

Comment: dispatch failed action in catchError so that you can subscribe inside component and set the spinner to false

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really new with angular, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are many approaches. I would say the following. 
There are 2 states here. One is the **authentication** state and one is the **loading** state.

You should have 2 reducers, one which handles the **loading** state and one the **authentication** part.

Depending on the UX design normally you would want the spinner to appear as as overlay each time a request is done, independently on which page/component you are.

One way to achieve this is by having a LoadingService which creates this overlay, loadingService which works with the loadingState (the example is done using the CDK Overlay from Angular Material).

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {

  private overlayRef: OverlayRef;
  private currentCount = 0;

  constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromLoading.loadingState)
    ).subscribe(loadingState => {
        if (loadingState.count > this.currentCount) {
          if (this.currentCount === 0) {
            this.overlayRef = this.cdkOverlayCreate();
            this.overlayRef.attach(new ComponentPortal(MatSpinner));
          }
        } else if (loadingState.count === 0 && this.currentCount !== 0) {
          this.overlayRef.dispose();
        }
        this.currentCount = loadingState.count;
      }
    );
  }

  cdkOverlayCreate(): OverlayRef {
    return this.overlay.create(
      {
        hasBackdrop: true,
        backdropClass: 'dark-backdrop',
        positionStrategy: this.overlay.position()
          .global()
          .centerHorizontally()
          .centerVertically()
      }
    );
  }
}
```

As I said before, you want the loading to appear independently of which component you are on it. This implies the manipulation of state should be done from an HTTP Interceptor. It may look like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.store.dispatch(new fromLoading.IncrementLoadingAction());
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.store.dispatch(new fromLoading.DecrementLoadingAction())));
  }
}
```

Each time a request is done, the loading state is incremented, and when a request finishes (failing or not) the state is decremented. The Loading Service subscribes to this state and react on changes by showing / hiding / keeping the overlay.

Once this is done, the loading will appear each time a request is done, including the authentication one.

For your example, you should dispatch an action of showing the loaded when you do the request, within the effect, and dispatch an action of hiding the loader on both **success** and **error case (catchError()=> {...})**. You can return multiple actions from an effect

```
return [{
      type: AuthActionTypes.LoginSuccessAction,
      payload: user
    }, {
      type: LoginActionTypes.DecrementLoading,
    }]
```

and you should also dispatch the action of incrementing the loading before doing the auth request.

```
this.store.dispatch(new LoadingIncrementAction())
this.authService.login(action.payload).
```

Comment: is there any simpler than this? haha

Comment: I made a catchError in my effects 

 catchError((res) => {
        if (res) {
          console.log(res);
          this.authService.isLoginSuccess = of(false); 
        }
        // debugger
        return of({});

and I am also declaring the value as true once the credentials are valid and still doesn't work tho. Got any ideas in my mind? huhu Im so frustrated with this